# After using z-index then why showing background object in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am making a popup to show some preload stuff but when but is not working. it is showing other element.

```
<html>
    <script src="http://www.flygoldfinch.com/wp-includes/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://www.flygoldfinch.com/wp-includes/js/nprogress.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.flygoldfinch.com/wp-includes/css/nprogress.css">
    <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('body').append('<div id="pbwrapper" style="width: 100%; position: fixed; left:0; top: 0; opacity:1; height: 800px; margin: 50px auto 0px auto; text-align: center; z-index: 10000; background-color : #fff;" > <h1 class="headline tac sans-serif">Wait while we loading Awesomeness</h1> </div>');
        NProgress.start();
        setTimeout( 
            function(){ 
                NProgress.done();
                jQuery('#pbwrapper').remove();
            }, 9000 
        );
    });
    </script>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">This is wrapper</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

That popup is created dynamicly by using jquery.
I made change in id="wrapper".
Is there any thisg wrong in my css. I fixed position of popup.
this is screenshot here [image]

Comment: Why are you using append in document start without any condition you can rather include it in HTML.

Comment: Well, where is your CSS?

Comment: @Rohit416 look inside Jquery  .append

Comment: it is in the div which i am appending div @Rohit416

Comment: The big question is this why showing back ground stuff when i am using z-index and position is fixed so why showing wrapper div element or thing @Riddler

Comment: Can you attach a screen capture?

Comment: @User97798 Because you have a 50 px margin for the #pbwrapper and it leaves some space at the top.

Comment: Can you show us what you're currently seeing  after running this? It's hard to imagine what the actual problem is.

Comment: have a look in image which i have given red border this is the wrapper

Comment: Change your `css` in your `jQuery`: `height: 100%; margin:0px;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have done a mistake in the jQuery like There is you have give the margin so remove it or just make it 0 and other thing @Vinayak is right make height =100%

So

Make Changes in this line

```
height: 800px; margin: 50px auto 0px auto;
```

To

```
height: 100%; margin: 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="wrapper">This is wrapper</div>
```

This div is in background and Pop up means top of your html body layer your popup div will come and you have fixed the height to 800px, that should be 100%

and also you are using jquery append ,it will append your html at the end body conntent